# Disable hints on all sites, when the rep on one is higher than X

Tags: feature-request, user-interface, user-accounts

After some rep threshold on SO, I noticed that the bubble tips were gone, that remind one to accept upvoted answers or upvote accepted answers.

However, when I switch to SU, SF or meta, where I didn't reach the threshold so far, the balloon tips are back again, but this time, they're really annoying, because they don't add any value for an experienced user.

Therefore I suggest, if a user has coupled her accounts, that she isn't provided the balloon tips, if her rep threshold is high enough on *any* of the sites.

Comment: Yes!!! I just wanted to ask for the same, but found this existing question. Imagine Jon Skeet coming to Bicycles SE and asking a question. Then he upvotes an answer and sees a hint about accepting it. "Well, thank you, Cap" - he will think. Any user with high enough rep already knows how to play this game, hints are useless and only distracting to them.